# JQuery - get dropdown value from popup

Tags: jquery, select, popup, readonly

My JQuery is loaded in my parent window.

From the parent I'm opening a popup window that contains a form `id='form1'`

Within the form is a dropdown list `id='site'`. Subject to what this is set I'm setting an input field as readonly or not.  By default the input is readonly. Changing the dropdown to an entry who's value is NOT 0 removes the readonly.

```
$('body').on('change', '#site', function(){
    if  ($(this).val() == '0') {    
        $('#siteField').prop('readonly', true);
    } else {
        $('#siteField').prop('readonly', false);
    }
});

<input type='text' id='siteField' name='siteField' value='<?php echo $site?>' readonly>
```

This works fine when I manually change the dropdown, the input will either be readonly or not.

However when the popup page is loaded, if the dropdown is set at a state other than 0 then I don't seem to be able to 'un readonly' the field.

I've tried adding the following after `$(document).ready(function() {` but this hasn't worked.

```
if  ($('#site').val() == '0') { 
    $('#siteField').prop('readonly', true);
} else {
    $('#siteField').prop('readonly', false);
}
```

console logging `$('#site').val()` as the popup opens shows UNDEFINED, but there is a dropdown set.

I'm assuming this is because the value is being loaded and the field set, but how do I read this in the popup ?

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use the value attribute

```
<option value="0a">0b</option>
```

In order to get 0a you use .val()
however, to get 0b you need to use .text()

Maybe that's what you are missing

Comment: Thanks I am using the `val()` but it doesn't load the value.

Comment: Can you confirm looking at the html rendered code that value is set there?

Comment: Yes there is a value set.

Comment: Looking at the code, I can get around this using PHP  `<input type='text' id='siteField' name='siteField' value='<?php echo $siteField ?>' <?php if ($site === '0') echo 'readonly' ?>>`  That should work as the form is loaded and use my original Jquery to update it as the dropdown changes.